# Asset pipeline stylesheet not being included

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Why are my stylesheets in `app/assets/stylesheets/` not being included by rails?
It's strange because my javasripts in `app/assets/javascripts/` are getting included.

I thought all assets in those directories should already be handled by a commented 
`=require_tree .` line in the CSS manifest file `application.css.scss`.

The line `//= require name_of_asset` in the application.js.coffee` seems to be working.

**application.css.scss**

```
@import "resets";
@import "bootstrap";
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

---

**file directory tree**

[image]

My actual full **application.css.scss**

```
@import "resets";
@import "bootstrap";
/* blanket styles */
@import "custom/cp_variables";
@import "custom/cp_custom";
@import "custom/cp_responsive";
/* plugin styles */
@import "spritz";
/*
 *= require select2
 *= require select2-bootstrap
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

I am having problems loading the "socionics.css.scss" file, along with all of its siblings.
The files nested in the under the "custom" subfolder work fine, since I used `@import` for those.

Also, leaving off .coffee suffix for some js files is intentional.

Comment: Is the problem that your other `CSS` files are not being loaded, or that `application.css` is just not loading? Each have different causes

Comment: I believe none of the stylesheets that are controller-specific are loading.

The application.css.scss is definitely working, as the included files are rendering styling html. I can remove and add them from the list and they change accordingly. So no problem with the application.css.scss file

Comment: And they're all inside the `/app/assets/stylesheets` folder?

Comment: yes sir. I'm wondering if it may be some kind of config setting that i accidently touched. i don't really have familiarity with them. Or perhaps a gem conflict...

Comment: I don't know! A good way to test will be to fire this command in your cmd: `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: i'm not sure what i'm looking for in the output of that command

Comment: Sorry! If it does not work, it will show an error explaining the issue :) If it does not, the error lies somewhere else :)

Comment: I decided to simply remove the `/*=require tree .` line, and explicitly manually include each file instead.

Comment: And it worked for you?

Comment: yes. I was hoping there was a way to retain usage of `tree .` but i guess you go with whatever works, right? time is precious. Besides, many articles suggest explicit inclusion anyway.

The question is still why the `tree .` might not be working, so I won't post an answer to my own question.

Comment: I always pursue what's *right* - which is always the hardest way! Can you post a screenshot of your `/stylesheets` folder?

Comment: I used to be like that, but a couple of factors changed my outlook recently: 1) time/efficiency/business mindset. 2) maintainability falls under agile decision making - the likelihood of change happening weighing the expected value costs, much like how you do in decision trees or poker. and i forgot: 3) some good old "who cares?" xp.

Comment: I think everyone has their own way of doing things :) But debating it won't help us understand the issue! Any chance you can post the screenshot? :)

Comment: ok, it's up. please refresh your page for my edits.

Comment: Nice - why don't you try using SCSS with globbing? I'll write a quick answer to show

Comment: please, thank you. globbing = using regex right, like you do in gitignore?

Answer (score 1):

You may benefit from [SCSS globbing](http://fuseinteractive.ca/blog/automatic-sass-imports-sass-globbing)

This is one of our actual `application.css.sass` files (`sass` & `scss` use the same pre-processor, so will work on both):

```
#app/assets/stylehseets/application.css.sass
@import variables
@import jquery/**/*
```

This should work out of the box (I installed the `sass-globbing` gem, but turned out we didn't need it!)

--

**Fix**

For you, I'd try this:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
@import "resets";
@import "bootstrap";

/* Blanket Styles */
@import "*" /* not sure if this will work for base dir */
@import "custom/*";

/* Plugins */
@import "spritz";
@import "select2";
@import "select2-bootstrap";
```

--

**Update**

In terms of ordering, I would presume `alphabetical`, and seems to confirm it [here](https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-globbing#caveats):

> CSS is order dependent, as such, using this approach within your
>   stylesheets to import styles that depend on the stylesheet's cascade
>   creates an opportunity for styles to change more unpredictably than a
>   manually asserted order. It is recommended that you only use globbing
>   where order is unimportant; E.g. importing of library files.

Comment: how is the order controlled? is it alphabetical?

Comment: Not sure to be honest! Will have to look it up of you want

Comment: Updated for you - you seem to be right in that it calls the files alphabetically (where load order is not important)

Comment: If this is important, I would recommend including important files specifically (we use `variables.css.sass` for example). That will allow you to call the files through globbing & retain the order

Comment: ^ you mean separate out the files you want to control the order of, list them explciitly, and then afterwards call any other files whose order don't matter relative to each other via the glob, right?

Comment: No problem - hope it helps?